# Assemble on Raspberry Pi 4 with makefile

Tags: assembly, makefile, raspberry-pi, arm

I just started today with ARM assembly on my raspberry pi 4. I found [this](https://thinkingeek.com/2013/01/09/arm-assembler-raspberry-pi-chapter-1/) tutorial witch seamed quite good, but it doesn't answer some of my questions. The first program that they create is:

```
/* -- first.s */
.global main
main:        
    mov r0, #2 /* Put a 2 inside the register r0 */
    bx lr      /* Return from main */
```

It can be assembled with:

```
as -o first.o first.s
gcc -o first first.o
```

and run with:

```
./first ; echo $?
```

To shorten this process this ````makefile``` is created:

```
all: first

first: first.o
    gcc -o $@ $+

first.o : first.s
    as -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -vf first *.o
```

My question now is how does this work and the filename `first` seams to be hardcoded. Can it take the file to compile as an argument, so the file that is to be assembled can have some arbitrary name? No tutorial I found really explains this.

Comment: You can have the make file assemble a random file by changing `first.o: first.s` to `%.o: %.s`.  However, it's not actually even required to have a Makefile here since this rule is implicitly defined in `make` itself.  Try it out; delete (or rename) `Makefile` and then type `make first`.  It should build just fine.

Comment: @fuz If you post your comment as an answer, i'll accept it!

Comment: To shorten the process?  Just use `gcc first.s`.  You only need to assemble separately if you're using an assembler other than `as`, like for x86 if you're using NASM.  GCC's `gcc` front-end knows what to do with `.s` files just like it knows what to do with `.c` or `.o` files.  So normally you'd do `gcc first.s && ./a.out` so you have one command to recall for your edit / built+run cycle.  (Or use `-o first` to set the name of the executable).  I've never used a Makefile for playing around with a one-file toy / experimental program.

Comment: @DinosaurMoritz Sorry, there isn't enough I can say to make an answer worthwhile.  Consider reading a make tutorial.

Comment: @fuz your comment was all I needed. Works fine now. Just wanted to accept your answer so nobody invests unnecessary time ..)